# Why is the find function returning NIL in this case?

Tags: common-lisp, equality, clos

I am new to Common Lisp, especially CLOS. I am using the REPL inside a package called Nyxt.

[Nyxt](https://nyxt.atlas.engineer/) is designed to be an infinitely extensible browser. Hence, the user can change the code and/or create extensions while the program is running. This is live hackability by design. My question is unrelated to the Nyxt package, but since it happened inside the package I thought it would be be better to provide more background info.

I do not understand the behavior of the function `find` in this concrete case.

I have this small list of instances representing URLs:

```
NYXT> small-list
(#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://duckduckgo.com/?q=google+analytics&ia=web>
 #<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://duckduckgo.com/l/?uddg=https%3A%2F%2Fanalytics.withgoogle.com%2F&notrut=duckduck_in>
 #<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA>
 #<QURI.URI:URI about:blank> #<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://ambrevar.xyz/>)
```

Then, I define as a variable the third element of the list:

```
NYXT> (defparameter wikipedia-page (third small-list))
WIKIPEDIA-PAGE

NYXT> wikipedia-page
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA>
```

Ok, it works as expected if I try to find the wikipedia-page inside the list:

```
NYXT> (find wikipedia-page small-list :test #'equal)
#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA>
```

Now, let me bound another instance to a variable:

```
NYXT> (defparameter blog (last small-list))
BLOG

NYXT> blog
(#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://ambrevar.xyz/>)
```

The problem is when I try to find it:

```
NYXT> (find blog small-list :test #'equal)
NIL
```

Now is the strangest part ever for me, the equality test works:

```
NYXT> (equal blog (last small-list))
T
```

Could anyone help me? Why find does not work for the `blog` case? Is this related to CLOS and how objects should be compared?

Thanks

Comment: the name `last` is confusing indeed, a useful/popular set of utilities on top of CL is Alexandria (https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) which defines `last-elt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given `small-list` as defined in the question, `(last small-list)` is the *list* `(#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://ambrevar.xyz/>)`. So, of course `(find (last small-list) small-list)` should be expected to return `nil`, since `small-list` does not contain the element `(#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://ambrevar.xyz/>)` (which is a *list*); rather `small-list` contains the *element* `#<QURI.URI.HTTP:URI-HTTPS https://ambrevar.xyz/>.`

Remember that [`last`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_last.htm) returns the last *cons* of a list (or the last `n` conses if you provide the optional argument). You could do: `(find (car (last small-list)) small-list)`.

Another possibility would be to use the `test` and `key` keyword arguments: `(find (last small-list) small-list :test #'equal :key #'list)`. But, I'm not sure when I would prefer this to the first solution.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you think `last` in common lisp returns the last element of a list. But if you look very carefully, it returns the last element packed into a list!
`(car (last small-list))` is what you think that `last` actually does.

```
(defparameter blog (car (last small-list)))

(find blog small-list :test #'equal)
```

Will work!

```
(equal blog (last small-list))
```

is not the correct test. Because `blog` you define before by using
`(last small-list)` therefore of course it must be `equal`.